# Класс возвращает тип имплементируемого интерфейса. Зачем?

Tags: java

В одном пакете находятся `Vector` - `interface` и `Vect` - `class`.   Причем класс имплементирует интерфейс. А в классе есть методы, которые возвращают тип `Vector`, то есть интерфейса. Какой в этом смысл?

Comment: О какой библиотеке идёт речь? Приведите исходный код. В стандартной java-библиотеке есть только класс `Vector`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы не завязываться на конкретную реализацию. Отчасти это принцип инкапсуляции. За счёт использование интерфейса в возвращаемом методе, тот, кто будет использовать класс, будет обращать внимание только на интерфейс, ему не важна реализация оного. Это уменьшает связанность компонентов.

К примеру:

```
public interface Vector{
   public Vector rotateAndReturn();
   public Vector somethingAndReturn();

   [...]
}

public class Vect implement Vector{
   public Vector rotateAndReturn(){
      // поворачиваем
      return this;
   }

   public Vector somethingAndReturn(){
      // что-то делаем
      return this;
   }
}
```

Зачем? Смысл появится, когда, к примеру, новую реализацию `Vector` захотите делать:

```
public class SuperVect implement Vector{
   public Vector rotateAndReturn(){
      // поворачиваем
      return this;
   }

    public Vector somethingAndReturn(){
      // что-то делаем
      return this;
   }
}
```

Теперь можно так:

```
Vector vector = new Vect();
vector1.rotateAndReturn().somethingAndReturn();
```

Можно тогда экземпляр другого класса создать и так же вызывать:

```
vector = new SuperVect ();
vector1.rotateAndReturn().somethingAndReturn();
```

Плюшка в использовании коллекции:

```
List<Vector> list = new ArrayList<Vector>();
list.add(new Vect());
list.add(new SuperVect ());
```

Теперь при прогонке мы с классами можем унифицировано работать:

```
list.forEach(vector -> vector.rotateAndReturn().somethingAndReturn());
```

Независимо от того, какой это объект на самом деле, за счёт того, что методы возвращают имплементируемый интерфейс, мы работаем с классами унифицировано.